# Heroku set git remote heroku but when adding I get error remote heroku already exists

Tags: git, heroku

Until now I was using connect to github with heroku but as I understand it is currently disabled. So it's my first time doing it through Heroku CLI.

I am following the tutorial on heroku. First I log in using heroku login. Then I would like to link my existing repo on github with `heroku git:remote -a my-app-name` but I get a error message saying  `set git remote heroku to ...`, when I try to set it with  `git remote add heroku ...` I get another error  `error: remote heroku already exists.`.

I have never used this before and I can't understand what should I do. How can I deploy my project from github to heroku?

Comment: Git itself is completely ignorant of Heroku. The opposite is not true: Heroku is terrifically smart about Git. I don't use Heroku myself but in general you run Heroku commands to tell Heroku to set up Git for you. Running Git commands directly (`git remote add heroku ...`) gets you the dumb interface, so that you need to know exactly what you're doing. If Heroku doesn't have a Heroku command to change the Heroku target for Git, you'll need to know exactly what to do here (which I don't!) but it will *probably* involve `git remote set-url heroku` rather than `git remote add heroku`.

Comment: I am following the exact instructions given in Heroku, how to deploy the project using git. Also git remote set-url heroku didn't change the error about heroku git:remote -a app-name @torek

Comment: `heroku git:remote` is an example of Heroku being smart about Git. `git remote set-url heroku <url>` is an example of Git being dumb about Heroku: Git will change the URL here, regardless of whether that's right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to deploy the project with just `git push heroku master`

Comment: This means you had already done the setup step previously. It won't work a second time, as it's already there.

Comment: Thanks. I figured the same as well but what I did not understand was that I was following the official setup tutorial by Heroku and I hadn't done that beforehand so I can't understand how that would work. @ceejayoz